# Ws Spring boot: Add saml assertion inside security header

Tags: spring-ws

This is my code:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class IncidenciesSAMLHeaderRequestCallback implements WebServiceMessageCallback {

    private final SAMLTicketProvider samlTicketProvider;
    private final VisorApiProperties visorApiProperties;

    @Override
    public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException, TransformerException {
        String samlAssertion = this.samlTicketProvider.getToken();

        SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage)message;
        SoapHeader header = soapMessage.getSoapHeader();
        StringSource headerSource = new StringSource(samlAssertion);

        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(headerSource, header.getResult());
    }
```

I was expecting my saml assertion was included into header. It's generating:

```xml
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="...">...</saml2:Assertion>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I need my saml assertion is inserted inside a `<wsse:Security>...</wsse:Security>`.

I mean, I need:

```xml
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="...">
      <saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="...">...</saml2:Assertion>
    </wsse:Security>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Any ideas?